# How to debug the "System" part of my Mac that is taking up space

Tags: hard-drive, macbook, disk-space

I am seeing [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o6GyX.png). I have been running a lot of Node.js data processing scripts to generate data on an external hard drive. I am logging a lot of stuff to the terminal windows that are running those processes. I am pretty sure there aren't any memory leaks in these (albeit hacked together) scripts. So I'm wondering what I can look at or which commands I can run to get a more fine-grained picture of what on my "System" is taking up space, so I can clear it out and make some more room on my MacBook hard drive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first you can navigate to Apple logo (top-left) in taskbar -> Storage tab --> manage and get an overview of what your system has allocated.

From terminal you can use the du command

```
du -sh ~
du -sh *
```

Try Disk Invetory X too.

hope this helps